# Can't upload chrome extension--.json file not selectable

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm going through Steven Foote's "Learning How to Program" book and the beginning section has us uploading a manifest.json file to chrome://extensions. Using http://jsonlint.com/, the code seems valid.

When I go to upload the .json file to the extension page, it is unselectable (can't click on the file")

https://i.stack.imgur.com/17IbQ.png

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: source code here: {
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "kittenbook",
 "description": "Replace photos on Facebook with kittens",
 "version": "0.0.1",

"content_scripts": [
{
 "matches": ["*://wwww.facebook.com/*"],
 "js": ["kittenbook.js"]
 }
 ]
}

Comment: have you tried to click on the select button ? In my memory, you have to select the folder of your etension, not the manifest file

Comment: also try this match pattern to match all facebook pages: "*://*.facebook.com/*"

Answer (score 2):

A manifest JSON file is useless by itself - it describes how to handle the rest of the content in the folder.

Which is why, in fact, you need to select the *folder* (that contains the manifest) to load as an unpacked extension.

You'll notice that the dialog in your screenshot asks for exactly that and the "Select" button is active even though you haven't selected any files. You're in the target directory and there's nothing extra you need to do.

And if, later, you publish to CWS, you'll need to provide a zip of your extension folder.